# Why split('TEST','') returns two extra elements:- ["","T","E","S","T",""]

Tags: hive

Why is the Hive split function returning two extra elements? My input string only has 4 characters but split returns an array with 6 elements.

```
hive> select split('TEST','');
OK
["","T","E","S","T",""]
```

My goal was to convert the input string to character array.

Comment: Because your delimiter is empty, then it matches the empty before and after TEST as well

Comment: But there is no empty before and after. I guess this is how it behaves. Anyway, thanks, I think I got the answer.

Comment: You mean there is no space before and after the word.  :-)  It uses a regular expression, and so giving it an empty string as the split criteria would cause it to match before and after the last characters.

Comment: @Dhiraj I described the issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51044214/2271325