# Hive convert a string to an array of characters

Tags: hive, hiveql

How can I convert a string to an array of characters, for example

```
"abcd" -> ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I know the split methd:

```
SELECT split("abcd","");

#["a","b","c","d",""]
```

is a bug for the last whitespace? or any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not actually a bug. Hive [split function](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFSplit.java) simply calls the underlying Java [`String#split(String regexp, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) method with `limit` parameter set to `-1`, which causes trailing whitespace(s) to be returned.

I'm not going to dig into implementation details on why it's happening since there is already a [brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27477312/2271325) that describes the issue. Note that `str.split("", -1)` will return different results depending on the version of Java you use.

A few alternatives:

1. **Use `"(?!\A|\z)"` as a separator regexp**, e.g. `split("abcd", "(?!\\A|\\z)")`. This will make the regexp matcher skip *zero-width matches* at the start and at the end positions of the string.
2. **Create a custom UDF** that uses either `String#toCharArray()`, or accepts `limit` as an argument of the UDF so you can use it as: `SPLIT("", 0)`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is a bug or that's how it works. As an alternative, you could use `explode` and `collect_list` to exclude blanks from a where clause

```
SELECT collect_list(l) 
FROM ( SELECT EXPLODE(split('abcd','') ) as l ) t 
WHERE t.l <> '';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know `collect_list` method, but the split's result is confusing.